# how to fix data in List<List<string>>

Tags: c#, list

I have a variable called result which is a

```
List<List<string>>
```

I want to parse each element and fix it (remove white spaces, etc)

```
            i = 0;
            foreach (List<string> tr in res)
            {
                foreach (string td in tr)
                {
                    Console.Write("[{0}] ", td);
                    td = cleanStrings(td); // line with error
                    i++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

    public string cleanStrings(string clean)
    {
        int j = 0;                
        string temp = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(clean, @"[\r\n]", "");
        if (temp.Equals("&nbsp;"))
        {
            temp = " ";
            temp = temp.Trim();
        }
        clean = temp;                        
        return clean;
    }
```

> Error 1   Cannot assign to 'td' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'

How would I fix this?

Comment: You cannot modify the iterator of a foreach loop.

Comment: You can modify objects, just not the iterator.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically you have to not use `foreach`. Iterators in .NET are read-only, basically. For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tr.Count; i++)
{
    string td = tr[i];
    Console.Write("[{0}] ", td);
    tr[i] = CleanStrings(td);
}
```

(Note that I've used the variable `i` which you were incrementing but not otherwise using.)

Alternatively, consider using LINQ:

```
res = res.Select(list => list.Select(x => CleanStrings(x)).ToList())
         .ToList();
```

Note that this creates a *new* list of *new* lists, rather than mutating any of the existing ones.

Comment: @mellamokb: Was just writing the LINQ version :)

Comment: @mellamokb This would be preferable though, especially if you are only modifying a small percentage of the items.

Comment: @Servy: I don't know... it depends on the context. I've become fond of non-mutating operations :)

Comment: @JonSkeet It depends.  Here I'd probably try to clean the data before populating the data structure in the first place, as a "best case scenario".

Comment: LINQ seems to be very popular. Any good resources 2 learn this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the Collection that you are enumerating over using a foreach, so just use regular for loops:

```
for (int m = 0; m < res.Count; m++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < res[m].Count; j++)
    {
        Console.Write("[{0}] ", td);
        res[m][j] = cleanStrings(res[m][j]);
        i++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must make the inner loop a `for` loop in order to get the index inside the list `tr`. This enables you to replace the entry in the list at this index. You can keep the outer `foreach` loop, however.

```
i = 0;
foreach (List<string> tr in res) {
    for (int k = 0; k < tr.Count; k++) {
        string td = tr.[k];
        Console.Write("[{0}] ", td);
        tr[k] = cleanStrings(td); // line with no error anymore
    }
    i += tr.Count;
    Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.WriteLine("Total number of items: {0}", i);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error implies, you're not going to be able to fix the content of a List by changing the iterator variable, and you have the same constraint in the outer foreach. There are a couple of approaches, but one you could try is as follows:

```
        i = 0;
        foreach (List<string> tr in res)
        {
            for (int currentItem; currentItem<=tr.Count; currentItem++)
            {
                Console.Write("[{0}] ", tr[currentItem]);
                res[i][currentItem] = cleanStrings(tr[currentItem]); // line with error
            }
            i++;
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```